# problem with mdk3

Tags: wireless

I have a problem in using mdk3 on kali.

I want to DOS my AP with deauthenticate packets. I use the command:

`Mdk3 mon0 d <AP mac address>`

I am sure that the command is true. It is not working and nothing happened, and the clients that connected to the related AP will not deauthenticate.

Comment: Why are you sure the command is correct?

Comment: When I use this command the packets send correctly to the AP but nothing happend